# URL routing in CodeIgniter3 is not going to the correct directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, url-routing

I just download CI and I copied the 2-folder application and system to my webfolder.

I moved index.php to be inside application and I have modified the .htaccess

My webfolder is `C:\onedrive\dropbox\template\`
and my access url is `http://localhost/template/application/index.php`

Every time I open `http://localhost/template/application/`, it always says:

> 404 Page Not Found, The page you requested was not found.

When I debugged CodeIgniter.php with `var_dump($RTR->class);`, I got:

```
'template'
```

That why my URL is always wrong. Why is this happening?

I just modified 'Router.php' in the method '_set_request' in the first line to exclude my URL for segmentation:

```
// akhyar : exclude url before index.php first
$excSegment = explode('/',config_item('base_url'));
$segments = array_diff($segments,array('index.php'));
foreach ($excSegment as $idxSegment => $valSegment) {
    $segments = array_values(array_diff($segments,array(urlencode($valSegment))));
}
```

became:

```
protected function _set_request($segments = array())
{
    // akhyar : exclude url before index.php first
    $excSegment = explode('/',config_item('base_url'));
    $segments = array_diff($segments,array('index.php'));
    foreach ($excSegment as $idxSegment => $valSegment) {
        $segments = Array_values(
            array_diff(
                $segments,
                array(urlencode($valSegment))
            )
        );
    }
    $segments = $this->_validate_request($segments);
    ...........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Your_controller";
```

and in controller file name should be (ex main) use `main.php`

an in side controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Main extends CI_Controller
    {

    }
```

Comment: do you try to install codeigniter 3 inside subfolder? try to install code igniter so need to access like http://localhost/folder/subfolder/subfolder, and controller will be always 'folder'

Comment: @user2020329 what you mean by sub folder??

Comment: i have folder c:\onedrive\dropbox\codeigniter, my root web is c:\onedrive\, so i need access my codeigniter with http://localhost/dropbox/codeigniter/application/, this cause controller name always 'dropbox' never go to main